# Play a sound file from internet when a button is clicked

Tags: android, button, audio, media-player

I'm trying to play a sound file on button click but my sound URL comes  form internet e.g http://www.example.com/sound.mp3. How can I play when button is clicked, using a Media Player.

**Example:** This is the way to Play Local file

```
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mmmm); 
         mp.start();
         }
         });
```

I want play this sound  http://www.example.com/sound.mp3 represent R.raw.mmmm , without downloading this sound.

Comment: By not downloading you mean streaming it? Android can't do real streaming yet as far as i know.

Answer (score 18):

Media Player has greate feature in android.You can handle all event that occurred.So this is the code to play a file(Either Local or Online Url)

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
//You can show progress dialog here untill it prepared to play
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when MediaPlayer
            //  is not able to play file. You can show error message to user
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to play this sound locally, you have to download it first.

You just cannot "play something from the internet" as the machine which is playing that sound is your local machine. It needs to have a copy the that MP3.

After that, there might be ways to start playing before the download complete, but there will be a download anyway.

**EDIT**: *AndroidDeveloper*, in another reply of that page, gave you information about how to do streaming (+1!). This corresponds to what I've stated above, so it seems there IS a way to start playing before the download actually completes, even though this download will have happened at the end.

Comment: but I see it play sound from the internet