# Call MP3 from Data Source

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am making an app in which i **need to call MP3 from Data Source [from Web URL]**, still i am calling from **Local Resource**,

I have stored these audios in this URL: http://mysite.com/audios/

please see below code:

```
     private int correctId(String id){
        if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("gayatri"))
            return R.raw.gayatri;
        else if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("guitar"))
            return R.raw.guitar;
        else if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("helo"))
            return R.raw.helo;
        else if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("msg"))
            return R.raw.msg;
        else if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("roja"))
            return R.raw.roja;
        else
            return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Link doesn't work and your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Player for playing audios locally or online. I've found this link, maybe this could help.

[Play a sound file from internet when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228405/play-a-sound-file-from-internet-when-a-button-is-clicked)